# Relation between government bond yields and mortgage rates?

Tags: interest-rates

Does anyone know any academic literature on how government bond yields are related to mortgage rates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you can see from Figure 4 on Page 18 the 30 year fixed rate mortgage has followed the 10 Year Treasury yield closely, but 1 or 1.5 percentage points higher. https://www.fhfa.gov/policyprogramsresearch/research/paperdocuments/working_paper_14-2.pdf